# Post Call to Load Balanced Wcf Rest Api using WebClient Sometimes getting Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, load-balancing, wcf-rest

A Web application calls internal WCF REST api. Application can call successfully service both dev and production. But sometimes user can not use because of exception. Application runs from desktop, ipad and other devices. It calls service using WebClient. I tried to reproduce error from dev but i cannot. The exception is as follows:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)
>
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)
>
> at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String
>   method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
>
> at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method,
>   String data)

Production environment is Windows server 2012 and load balance. I could not reproduce the error but it happens all of a sudden and user cannot explain the flow of exception raise. So, i could not find the pattern to narrow down the issue. I am going through the code and guessing the error and modify logic. I searched in Google a lot but could not find any clues.

The way i am calling the Rest Api is as follows:

```
try{
var vm = new { lots of fields data };

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
   client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
   client.UploadString(new Uri("http://myservicename/postjsondata"), 
   "POST", dataString);
 }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //write to log file.
}
```

I have been unable to reproduce this error. Is there any way to reproduce this error in production?

Comment: The load balance is the difference...something about state (of the client calls) maybe being jiggered from one load balanced machine to the next during calls.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am not clear the explanation. Would you make it elaborate please.

Comment: Remove the Load balancer and I would bet the problem goes away. The issue AFAIK is in your load balancer and how it reacts.

Comment: One server is not enough based on umber of requests processing.  No way to remove load banancer because it is company's structure. Based on this structure, i have to find a solution.

Comment: I have worked a job where we had issue with load balanced services. I don't think it is your situation. But we had to discover why our client's were failing when switching between servers during client sessions. I wish I could offer more insight. :-(